# How to get ip address of product reviewer

Tags: magento2.4, product-review

I want to get the IP address of the product review and insert it into a database.
I already have the 'review_ip_address' column in the 'review' table and try to modify Magento_review/Controller/Product/Post.php from

```
$review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_PENDING)
->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
->setStores([$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()])     
->save();
```

to

```
$review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_PENDING)
->setReviewIpAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
->setStores([$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()])     
->save();
```

by adding `->setReviewIpAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])`
but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this

```
$ipAddress = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Hopefully, this works for you

Note: In localhost/local machine you will get 127.xx.xx.xx not IP you are expecting

Note2: Please validate or sanitize the IP before saving it

Thanks

Comment: It's work for me thank you.

Comment: Edit:: `$ipAddress = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); ` due to `Unparenthesized 'a ? b : c ? d : e' is deprecated. Use either '(a ? b : c) ? d : e' or 'a ? b : (c ? d : e)'`

Comment: $ipAddress = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

Answer (score 0):

```
$objctManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$remote = 
$objctManager->get('Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress');

echo $remote->getRemoteAddress();
```

Comment: directly using object manager it's not good practice @surbhi Doshi